# How to get Haskell to recognize functions as applicative functors

Tags: haskell, types, applicative

I'm new to Haskell and still don't understand how to deal with their type system. My problem is that I'm playing around with the **sequenceA** function from the book *Learn You a Haskell For Great Good*. Here's the function:

```
sequenceA :: (Applicative f) => [f a] -> f [a]
sequenceA = foldr (liftA2 (:)) (pure [])
```

I tried to adapt it to a specific use, so I wrote the following function:

```
binner :: Int -> [Int -> Int]
binner n = (map (\x -> bin x) [n, (n-1) .. 1])
  where bin n = (`mod` 2) . (`div` 2^(n-1))
```

I have no problem using these functions separately. For example, the following works great in GHCi:

```
sequenceA (binner 4) 10
```

If I type the following in GHCi,

```
:t (sequenceA (binner 4))
```

It shows the type as:

```
(sequenceA (binner 4)) :: Int -> [Int]
```

However, I can't figure out how to combine the functions. Intuitively, it seems I should be able to do the following, using the same type that GHCi showed:

```
binner :: Int -> [Int]
binner n = foldr (liftA2 (:)) (pure []) $ (map (\x -> bin x) [n, (n-1) .. 1])
  where bin n = (`mod` 2) . (`div` 2^(n-1))
```

But that throws an error compiling:

> Couldn't match type ‘[a0]’ with ‘Int’
>         Expected type: [Int]
>           Actual type: [[a0]]

I tried messing with the type declaration, but haven't figured out how to fix it.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You tried to use the type of `sequenceA (binner 4)` with the body of essentially `\n -> sequenceA (binner n)`. Since what you wrote takes an `Int` that what you gave to `:t` doesn't, you need to add an `Int ->` to the beginning of the type signature to represent the `n`:

```
binner :: Int -> Int -> [Int]
binner n = foldr (liftA2 (:)) (pure []) $ (map (\x -> bin x) [n, (n-1) .. 1])
  where bin n = (`mod` 2) . (`div` 2^(n-1))
```

You could instead keep the type, but hardcode the 4:

```
binner :: Int -> [Int]
binner = foldr (liftA2 (:)) (pure []) $ (map (\x -> bin x) [4, (4-1) .. 1])
  where bin n = (`mod` 2) . (`div` 2^(n-1))
```